# Show json from database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm working with a json structure that displays a quiz, but right now I don't understand how to display it properly please help me, I want to read information from database and show in below json structure, i thank you

```
[
  {
    "question_id" : 0,
    "question": "What is the original native name of Mount Rainier?",
    "answers": [
      {"id": 0, "text": "Tahoma"},
      {"id": 1, "text": "Shuksan"},
      {"id": 2, "text": "Stillaguamish"}

    ],
    "correct": 0
  },
  {
    "question_id" : 1,
        "question" : "Which image shows a close-up of the Nisqually Glacier?",
        "answers"  : [
            {"id"  : 0, "image" : "images/quizImages/glacier_01.jpg" },
            {"id"  : 1, "image" : "images/quizImages/glacier_02.jpg" },
            {"id"  : 2, "image" : "images/quizImages/glacier_03.jpg" },
            {"id"  : 3, "image" : "images/quizImages/glacier_04.jpg" }
        ],
        "correct"  : 3
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: do you use MySQLi  or PDO ?

Comment: Where are you stuck, exactly? See the [tour] and [ask]...you need to ask something more focused and specific. We don't know if you even know how to write a SELECT query, or whether there's a more particular problem about the JSON or something.

Comment: @The House Please share your effort of till where you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fetch your data from the database and make a `multidimensional array` using the data that is getting the database.
2. Apply `json_encode` on final `array`